# Nested For loops are stopping short (beginner)

Tags: python, api, for-loop

I'm using a couple of nested For loops in a script I wrote to scrape Reddit's API, but the script seems to stop short after scraping a single post. It runs all the way through the loop, but for whatever reason won't repeat the process. Anyone have an idea what's going on here?

```
for i in subreddit:
    submission = reddit.submission(id=i.id)
    comments = submission.comments
    ts = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(i.created_utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    tree = ('Comment section:')
    for comment in comments:
        body = ('----\nComment:' + comment.body + '\n----')
        tree = tree + body
        if len(comment.replies) > 0:
            for reply in comment.replies:
                bodyrply = ('\nREPLY: \n' + reply.body + '----')
                tree = tree + bodyrply
        else:
            tree = tree
    continue
    filewriter.writerow({'title': i.title,'author': i.author,
                         'original content': i.is_original_content,
                         'selfpost': i.is_self,
                         'time created': ts,
                         'stickied': i.stickied,
                         'locked': i.locked,
                         'NSFW': i.over_18,
                         'selftext': i.selftext,
                         'comment forest': tree,
                         'number of comments': i.num_comments,
                         'score': i.score,
                         'upvote ratio': i.upvote_ratio,
                         'permalink': i.permalink,
                         'url': i.url})
```

Comment: FYI there's no need for `tree = tree`.

Comment: filewriter.writerow can never run if it is directly after a continue since the continue will always cause the code to jump to the start of the loop and if the for loop is complete it will just jump to the end of the loop, completely skipping the line

Answer (score 0):

This is not the final answer, but it may help narrow down the issue. Add some checks in the code to confirm the initial data is what you expect.

```
print("len sr =", len(subreddit))  # is this a valid list greater than 1 ?
for i in subreddit:
    print("i =", i)  # what object are you dealing with ?
    submission = reddit.submission(id=i.id)
    comments = submission.comments
    ts = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(i.created_utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    tree = ('Comment section:')
    print("len cmts =", len(comments))  # are there any comments ?
    for comment in comments:
        body = ('----\nComment:' + comment.body + '\n----')
        tree = tree + body
        if len(comment.replies) > 0:
            for reply in comment.replies:
                bodyrply = ('\nREPLY: \n' + reply.body + '----')
                tree = tree + bodyrply
        else:
            pass    # tree = tree
    print("i2 =", i)   # make sure the code got this far
    continue
```